# Javascript for Bigcommerce cart not working in IE

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

The following (very simple, not fantastic) JS script is being used in one of my client's Bigcommerce carts. It's designed to pick up a given BC customer group, and check the status of a given element (a radio button), then either show a given selector, or let it remain hidden. It works fine in every browser except IE, where it runs as normal, but never shows the selector, even when the console shows no errors. (Why is it running on a one-second interval? Because BC loads the cart four pieces at a time, but from the same page. Whee!)

Is there a JS function being used here that IE doesn't support? I've reviewed all the functions, and I'm not seeing anything, but you know how blind you can get from staring at the same code for a few hours.

[edit: It appears IE is picking up the keyphrase in the script, even though innerText isn't supposed to do that. But at least I'm a step closer to a solution!]

```
<script>
window.onload = setInterval(hideCC, 1000);

function hideCC ()
 {
/* Hide CC payment option for below listed groups only */
/* Add new customer groups with comma-separated list (i.e. [39,42,87]) */
var customergroup = [27,32,22,65,2,69,72,74,79,78,87,84,60,61,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,62,63,70,83,8,5];
/* Hide CC payment option for those using International Freight */
var intlFreight = document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf('International Freight');
/* Check state of wire transfer button; if it's checked, we don't need to do any of this */
var wireChecked = document.getElementById("radio-bankdeposit").checked;
if (wireChecked == true) {
    return;
}
else {
/* If the customergroup belongs to one of those listed above OR the text "International Freight" appears on the page, that will trigger this if */
if(customergroup.indexOf({{{customer.customer_group_id}}}) > -1 || intlFreight > -1 ) { 
/* console.log({{{customer.customer_group_id}}}); */
document.querySelector("#micro-app-ng-checkout > div > div > main > ol > li.checkout-step.checkout-step--payment.optimizedCheckout-checkoutStep > div.checkout-view-content > form > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div > ul > li.form-checklist-item.optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item.form-checklist-item--selected.optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item--selected").style.display="none"; 
}
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing with? Any errors when you check the console in IE dev tools?

Comment: I'm testing with IE11, and I believe I've identified the problem: despite using innerText (which should avoid this), IE is picking up the use of "International Freight" _in the script itself_, and triggering the if.

Comment: Ideally, what I'd like to do is look for the string only in the class "shippingOption-desc", but the code 

`var intlFreight = document.getElementsByClassName("shippingOption-desc").innerText.indexOf('International Freight');`

is clearly not the right way to do it, and I cannot work the right way out, despite (or perhaps because of) several early morning hours scouring Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Is using jQuery an option? Or does the solution need to be vanilla javascript?

Comment: jQuery is, delightfully, definitely an option!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the jQuery version of checking for the string within the "shippingOption-desc" class. Hopefully this will get around the issue with IE and innerText :)

```
var intlFreight = $('.shippingOption-desc').text().indexOf('International Freight');
```

Comment: Not enough upvotes in the world! Thank you, Karen White, that has worked perfectly!